# Are queries on the "__key__" property strongly consistent with GAE datastore?

Tags: java, php, python, google-app-engine, go

I know generally queries on the GAE datastore are eventually consistent. However I don't see why queries on `__key__` should not be strongly consistent as I presume this is what the datastore Get function uses.

Can anyone confirm querying by `__key__` is strongly consistent?

Comment: I would seriously doubt it.  You are still operating on an index, in this case an index of keys rather than some other property.  The index is still updated with the same consistency rules as all other indexes.

Comment: I could imagine though that the `__key__` index is treated specially by datastore `put` operations so that a `put` only returns once it has updated it. Therefore strong consistency can be guaranteed between `put` and `get` operations.

Comment: I don't interpret it that way. A get needs no index , the query you perform needs an index.  If you believe otherwise run some tests.

Comment: Tests done! . Queries without an ancestor filter return only eventually consistent results even if   ``__key__`` filter is used. You can't even use it in transactions(just like any other ancestor-less query) so basically there is no difference between ``__key__`` or any other kindless query in terms of consistency.

Comment: @themihai awesome - conclusive proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query will be consistent only on ancestor queries. Otherwise is not consistent even if the index contains key entries.
This is because writes are applied in two phases, one to write your data and other to update indexes. Get by key neves uses an index so its always correct.
I assume that you are generating semi-secuential keys otherwise a query with key wouldnt be useful. Beware however that appengine now recommends to spread your keys so they cover a large space and is thus better distributed in bigtable.